# Angular JS passing many variable md-autocomplete to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i just starting to learn angular JS a month ago. And found something difficult. 
I have the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/nsu6Pj?p=info

```
<input id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()" ng-model="data"/>
  selected = {{data}}
```

As you can see, there is a list of available tags. i want to pass the selected value in the index.html page to next.html page by clicking the button.

Actually i want pass not just 1 parameter. Just like md-autocomplete in angular material.
[Here is the image for example parameters i want to pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh8KD.png)

I hope you guys can help me :) Thanks.

Comment: can you put up a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're passing multiple values, you can choose to hold your values in an array or an object. I personally would just set your complete function to push the values to an array.

Now, as for exchanging data - You have three options that I can think of:

1. create a service that allows controllers to communicate with each other. You could then use that service to set a variable in one controller (holding your tags) and then use same service in a different controller to get the value.
2. broadcast an event in one controller with $rootScope.$broadcast and then listen to the event with $rootScope.$on
3. Save the data to the browser's cookies with angular's $cookieStore.

Now the way your stuff is actually set up you're instantiating a new module and controller in each page so options 1 and 2 are out. Here's how I set up saving the values in the cookies.